# Track if connection to certain URL gets established on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, connection, url, surveillance

I found with the analysis tool fiddler that a program establishes sometimes a connection to an extern server. Now, the goal is to track continuously in the background if there is a connection established to this certain URL and possible make actions (like writing a log) afterwards. Is that possible with tools already on board in Windows 8.1/10, or do I need additional tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using [**Wireshark**](https://www.wireshark.org/). Get the IP of the URL you want to monitor and filter for that, and have Wireshark log [only packets pertaining specifically to that IP addy](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/14828/how-to-capture-packets-only-tofrom-specific-ip):

1. Set a [Capture Filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) for the scan: `host 172.18.5.4` #replace IP with your target.
2. Dump your capture data to a file with the `dumpcap` command.
3. Set Wireshark (or better yet, its command-line counterpart, [TShark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)) to run as a [Windows Service](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/05/tshark-as-a-service-on-windows-7-by-joke-snelders.html) (if that method is outdated, try doing [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) instead).